# SQL Select only products and prices that have changed in price since a specified date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The tables look like this:

tblProducts (around 200k records)

```
SKU,Title,CategoryID
100,Apple,0
101,Orange,0
102,Carrot,1
```

tblCategories

```
CategoryID,CategoryName
0,Fruit
1,Vegetables
```

tblPrices (around 10m records)

```
SKU,BuyPrice,SellPrice,Timestamp
100,1,2,2013-1-1 23:04
100,3,6,2013-1-2 19:04
100,4,8,2013-1-3 21:04
100,4,8,2013-1-4 20:04
100,4,8,2013-1-5 22:04
```

I need to get the current BuyPrice of all products (the most recent one from tblPrices) and compare it to the latest BuyPrice at the time of X days ago from NOW(). I need only the products that changed in BuyPrice.

This is so I can answer the question, 'what products changed in price over the last X days?'. Given the small set of data above, I would get an empty table for 1 days or 2 days, but for 3 days, I would want to retrieve:

```
SKU,Title,CategoryName,OldBuyPrice,OldSellPrice,NewBuyPrice,NewSellPrice, NBP/OBP
100,Apple,Fruit,       3,          6,           4,          8,            2.00
```

and for 4 days:

```
SKU,Title,CategoryName,OldBuyPrice,OldSellPrice,NewBuyPrice,NewSellPrice, NBP/OBP
100,Apple,Fruit,       1,          2,           4,          8,            4.00
```

I've been searching for similar solutions on the net, but haven't found one. Any ordering is fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I was using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Also, NBP/OBP is equal to NewBuyPrice/OldBuyPrice, so I can see the magnitude of the change. Thanks.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is doable.  There's a decent windowing-function version, although there may still be better ways to do this:

```
WITH Current_Price (sku, buyPrice, sellPrice) as 
                   (SELECT sku, buyPrice, sellPrice
                    FROM (SELECT sku, buyPrice, sellPrice,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku
                                                   ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as rownum
                          FROM price) t
                    WHERE rownum = 1),

 Price_Back_Previous_Days (sku, buyPrice, sellPrice) as 
                          (SELECT sku, buyPrice, sellPrice
                           FROM (SELECT sku, buyPrice, sellPrice,
                                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku
                                                         ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as rownum
                                 FROM price
                                 WHERE timestamp < DATEADD(DAY, -3, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))) t
                           WHERE rownum = 1)

SELECT p.sku, p.title, c.categoryName,
       prev.buyPrice as oldBuyPrice, prev.sellPrice as oldSellPrice,
       curr.buyPrice as newBuyPrice, curr.sellPrice as newSellPrice,
       CASE WHEN prev.buyPrice = 0 
            THEN curr.buyPrice
            ELSE 1.0 * curr.buyPrice / prev.buyPrice END as 'NBP/OBP' 
FROM Product p
JOIN Category c
     ON c.categoryId = p.categoryId
JOIN Current_Price curr
     ON curr.sku = p.sku
JOIN Price_Back_Previous_Days prev
     ON prev.sku = p.sku
     AND (prev.buyPrice <> curr.buyPrice
          OR prev.sellPrice <> curr.sellPrice)
```

Which yields the expected

```
SKU  TITLE  CATEGORYNAME  OLDBUYPRICE  OLDSELLPRICE  NEWBUYPRICE  NEWSELLPRICE  NBP/OBP
100  Apple  Fruit         1            2             4            8             4
```

(Have a working [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00ec5/18), with an specific date substituted for `GETDATE()` for future-reasons.)

You'll notice that I'm using `-3` (and not `-4`, as might be expected), because I'm attempting to retrieve the same value for 'as of this date', *regardless of when (during the day) the query is run*.  Obviously the 'current price' can still change (although adding a timestamp parameter there as well could fix that); however, this should make sure that you're looking at a consistent price throughout a given day.

Comment: Just for the benefit of anyone who may come across this thread: change CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) to CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, GETDATE()). I was confused why I would seem to get yesterday's price drops each time I ran the query, but this fixed it. Also, account for division of 0 in '1.0 * curr.buyPrice / prev.buyPrice'

Comment: @drspa44 - The reason I was using 'date' as opposed to 'smalldatetime', was that using that meant the 'previous' row was based on _the time of day the query was run_, probably not what you want.  If my query is deficient in some way, please update your question with 'failing' data.  Your point about division by 0 is good though, and I'll update the query (and SQL Fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create the table oldtpc which will get the products which has maximun of date after X number of days. And another newtpc which has prices with most recent date. And in the on condition between 'oldtpc' and and 'newtpc' I am checking that those dates do not match

```
select tp.SKU, tp.Title, tc.CategoryName, oldtpc.BuyPrice, oldtpc.Sellprice, newtpc.buyprice, newtpc.Sellprice
from tblProducts tp
join  tblCategories tc 
on tp.CategoryId= tc.CateogryId
join (select SKU, BuyPrice, SellPrice, max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp 
             from tblPrices new
             where DATEDIFF ( dd, timestamp, getdate()) < @xdays
             group by SKU, BuyPrice, SellPrice ) as newtpcnewtpc 
on tp.SKU = newtpc .sku 
join (select SKU, BuyPrice, SellPrice, max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp 
             from tblPrices old 
             where DATEDIFF ( dd, timestamp, getdate()) >= @xdays 
             group by SKU, BuyPrice, SellPrice ) as oldtpc 
on oldtpc.SKU = tp.SKU and oldtpc.timestamp <> newtpc.timestamp
```

PS: some syntax might be wrong, but I think the general idea should work fine

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried this and its retrieved all of the price changes that have ever happened, regardless of time from today.

Comment: made an edit, so that that the time difference between old and new is exactly n number of days.. can you give you a try now

Comment: This seems to work for most of my data, but I'm not sure it'll retrieve products where the price has changed, but the tblPrices records are not regular. For example, if I had two records for Apples, one from today and one from 10 days ago, if I run the 1 day query, I'd still like to see this change, as I'm comparing the latest price from 2 different points in time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to return anything unfortunately. If I can't get this to work, I wouldn't mind going through the tables, current prices and X days ago prices in parallel in my program (vb.net).

Comment: found the mistake.. you should swap the getdate and timestamp in datediff function.. will make the edit..

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid. Would you be able to tell me how to just get the current prices as of a particular date or X days ago? I think I'm going to have to go through each product with a program to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa05e/2)

```
Select 
   tt.SKU,tt.BuyPrice,tt.SellPrice,tr.BuyPrice As NewBuyPrice,tr.SellPrice As NewSellPrice, tr.BuyPrice/tt.BuyPrice NNBP 
From
(
   select SKU, Max(Timestamps) timestamps
   from t
   Group by t.SKU
) t
Join t tr on t.SKU = tr.SKU AND t.timestamps = tr.Timestamps
Join t tt ON t.SKU = tt.SKU
AND DATEDIFF(D, tt.timestamps, t.timestamps) = 4
AND tt.BuyPrice <> tr.BuyPrice
```

Comment: Thanks for putting that together. It is close to what I want to a achieve, but I choose a number of days, I want to get a list of the products that changed within those days, rather than X days ago. If I change = 4 to <= 4, this might be close enough. I'll just check it with my data.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to create two tables as ajp is suggesting, as I'm getting lots of duplicate rows (probably since tblPrices is sometimes populated twice a day for some products).